# window.frames.length returns 0 in chrome and Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

I have this issue on Chrome and firefox, **window.frames.length** inside the function **crse_FrameExists()** always returns zero when actually it should return value 3 and true in order to proceed. I have no issues on IE9. Does anyone know why this happens. Any work around will be useful...
Thanks,
Code Snippets below:

```
alert(window.frames.length);
```

returns 0 as suppose to 3 in IE

Answer (score 2):

It's illegal to put your `frameset` in the `head` or in a `body`.

Put it directly after the `head` (without `body`) and you'll be fine.

For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script>
        function crse_FrameExists(frameName){
            for (i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
                if (window.frames[i].name == frameName) return(true);
            }
            return(false);
        }
        window.onload=function(){
            alert("crse_FrameExists('fra_header'):" + crse_FrameExists('fra_header') );
        };
    </script>
</head>
    <frameset id="Nav4mainFrameset" framespacing="0" border="false" frameborder="0" rows="76,*">
        <frame name="fra_minimain" id="fra_minimain" scrolling="no" noresize src="index2.html">
        <frameset cols="188,*">
            <frame name="fra_header" id="fra_header" scrolling="no" noresize src="index2.html">
            <frame name="fra_content" id="fra_content" scrolling="auto" noresize src="index2.html">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Don't forget to open your page using `http://` and not `file://` for your tests as Chrome's security model consider each file as a domain.

And don't put `for="window" event="onload()"` in your script element : that's not normalized and won't work on non MS browsers. You have to use a standard onload solution like in my example.

Comment: Corrected that, it was a mistake from my part, frameset is outside the <head> tag. Thanks for bringing that to my notice.

Comment: When putting the frameset outside the head and without body, I verified that `window.frames.length` does have a value of `3`. Don't forget to wait for document loading (using onload) before you call your count.

Comment: Don't forget to use http:// and not file:// for your tests as Chrome's security model consider each file as a domain.

Comment: Thanks but I am still not able to get this to work, I put the files into my localhost

Comment: Are you really waiting for the document to be loaded ? The `for="window" event="onload()` is useless as it's a IE thing. I've updated my example to demonstrate the call of your function.

Comment: okay this works but y does it not work through external JS... Its not working in Firefox and Chrome...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13606/discussion-between-bluesaph-and-dystroy)